# Find previous or next number in array from a given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, closest

I have a requirement whereby I need to find the previous or next number in an array from a given number. I've seen the following example which returns the closest number from a given number.

```
var values = [0, 7, 10, 17];
var givenNumber = 5;
var closest = values.reduce(function (previous, current) {
  return (Math.abs(current - givenNumber) < Math.abs(previous - givenNumber) ? current : previous);
});
console.log(closest); // outputs 7
```

How do I go about returning the previous or next number closest to the given number? For example

- If givenNumber = 5, then closest previous number would be 0
- If givenNumber = 5, then closest next number would be 7
- If givenNumber = 8, then closest previous number would be 7
- If givenNumber = 8, then closest next number would be 10
- If givenNumber = 15, then closest previous number would be 10
- If givenNumber = 15, then closest next number would be 17
- If givenNumber = 20, then closest previous number would be 17
- If givenNumber = 20, then closest next number would be 0

For more information about the **reduce** function please see the following

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff679975%28v=vs.94%29.aspx
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_reduce.htm

Comment: Please provide at least a code sample that is actually testable. (Yours is missing a closing bracket, and uses multiple variables that are not defined in the code you have shown.)

Comment: Not knowing what the reduce function does exactly, but guessing on its functionality, you could adapt the criterium by comparing it to your value: `((Math.abs(current - currentFrame) < Math.abs(previous - currentFrame)) !== value ? ... etc` (or `===` depending on the needs) That way when value changes, whether current or previous is used reverses too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var values = [0, 7, 10, 17];

function find(values, goal) {
  var closest = values.reduce(function(closest, current) {
    return (Math.abs(goal - current) < Math.abs(goal - closest) ? current : closest);
  }, Infinity);
  return closest;
}

function test(values, goal) {
  snippet.log(goal + ': ' + find(values, goal));
}

test(values, 5);
test(values, 8);
test(values, 0);
test(values, 12);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: If goal is 5 and I needed it to return the closest previous entry, i.e. 0, how would this work?

Comment: For example, if goal is 5 then I need to be able to find either the previous value in the array (0) or the next value (7)

Comment: @SeanDooley do you mean, if the previous value is not there then the next value